# How nodetool garbagecollect will remove the shadowed tombstone data from the sstables

Tags: cassandra, nodetool

I have gone through nodetool garbagecollect documentation, it is not mentioned how this command removes shadowed tombstone data from multiple and overlapping sstables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Behind the scenes, `nodetool garbagecollect` runs a single-SSTable compaction.  Which means that it's not running on multiple SSTable files.  Essentially, the compaction process just runs on one SSTable file at a time, removing any eligible tombstones, and rewriting the file.

> But, as per [issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-7019](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-7019) overlapping sstables are used as source of tombstones to filter out deleted content, and will not appear in the resulting single sstable compaction. Let's say, shadowed data is present in the sstable1 and tombstone is present in sstable2, how shadowed data in sstable1 will be removed without knowing its tombstone in the sstable2 with nodetool garbagecollect?

In re-reading through that ticket's comments, it sounds like that scenario is indeed covered.

> will not appear in the resulting single sstable compaction.

I don't think that's an entirely correct statement.  From my understanding:

- The process is timestamp-aware.  So it knows that data in SSTable1 is older than the tombstone in SSTable2.
- Tombstones that cover data in multiple SSTable files are identified.
- Despite its name, Single SSTable compaction takes multiple SSTable files into consideration.
- In the scenario described, the single SSTable compaction on SSTable1 also identifies that some of its data is covered by a tombstone in SSTable2 (or any others).
- After determining that the tombstone is eligible, the single SSTable compaction removes the data for that partition from SSTable1. It then processes SSTable2 and knows it can safely remove the tombstone in question.

**Edit 20230306**

So I asked Branimir (the developer who wrote [CASSANDRA-7019](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-7019)) to take a look at this discussion.  He mentioned that the SSTables are processed by the *lower* timestamps first, so I've adjusted my points above to reflect this.  He also offered the following notes to help clarify the process:

Additional sstables are used in two ways:

1. older sstables to see if a tombstone can be dropped (this is done for all compactions, not just garbagecollect.
2. newer sstables to see if anything deletes data in the current one (this is garbagecollect-specific).

The order is as follows:

SStable1, having a lower min timestamp, is processed first. The single-sstable compaction should find, by (2), the tombstone in SStable2 and drop the covered data.

SStable2 is processed then. Because we already processed SStable1, there should be no data found in (1) when the tombstone is processed and the tombstone can be dropped.

If we do normal compactions, there is no (2), the data remains and (1) finds it when processing SStable2, i.e. neither the data nor tombstone can be dropped.

Note: (2) can be tuned on also by setting `provide_overlapping_tombstones: row` or `cell` in the compaction options. It may slow down compaction considerably (esp. with STCS), so it's to be used with caution.

Independently, any tombstone that is still within `gc_grace` won't be dropped regardless if any data is found. Still, if `garbagecollect` managed to remove the data, a later normal compaction (after the grace expires) should be able to drop it.

Another note: (1) only uses the bloom filter to check if data is covered by a tombstone; i.e. if anything in the partition remains live, no tombstone can be dropped.

Comment: But, as per https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-7019 overlapping sstables are used as source of tombstones to filter out deleted content, and will not appear in the resulting single sstable compaction. Let's say, shadowed data is present in the sstable1 and tombstone is present in sstable2, how shadowed data in sstable1 will be removed without knowing its tombstone in the sstable2 with nodetool garbagecollect?

Comment: I'm curious to know how this compaction maintains the tombstone state information to remove the shadowed data first and then the actual tombstone and by the way table gc_grace_second will not make tombstone eligible for removal, will in this case the shadowed data is force removed.

Comment: @RohitThakur I had a quick discussion with Branimir, and added some notes that will hopefully add some clarity here.

Comment: How this works when there are 2 data folders? Say my shadowed data is present in the SSTable of data0 folder and tombstone is present in the SSTable of data1 folder.

Comment: Waiting for your reply on my previous comment.

Comment: Can you please tell how the above use case mentioned in the previous comment works?

Comment: @RohitThakur if you have an additional question, please ask a new question.  Continually adding to an existing answer is discouraged.  That being said, using multiple data directories per node certainly has both its nuances and unique failure modes when it comes to compaction and tombstone behaviors.